# Apache/Nifi 1.12.1 Docker Image Issue

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-nifi

I have a Dockerfile based on `apache/nifi:1.12.1` and want to expand it like this:

```
FROM apache/nifi:1.12.1
RUN mkdir -p /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/flow
```

Thing is that the folder isn't created when I'm building the image from Linux distros like Ubuntu and CentOS. Build succeeds, I run it with `docker run -it -d --rm --name nifi nifi-test` but when I enter the container through `docker exec` there's no `flow` dir.

Strange thing is, that the `flow` dir is being created normally when I'm building the image through Windows and Docker Desktop. I can't understand why is this happening.

I've tried things such as `USER nifi` or `RUN chown ...` but still...

For your convenience, this is the base image:
https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.12.1/nifi-docker/dockerhub/Dockerfile

Take a look at this as well:
[This is what looks like at the CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xevgS.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you run the container? If you volume map anything anywhere in the /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf path, that will hide the directory.

Comment: With `docker exec nifi /bin/bash` and I'm landing at `/opt/nifi/nifi-current` as it's the `WORKDIR` in the base image.

Comment: `docker exec` doesn't run the container. It runs a command against an already running container. You must have a `docker run` command or a docker-compose file or something. But that might also be the reason. If you don't stop the container and start a new one, your new image isn't used.

Comment: Yeap my bad, I run with `docker run -it -d --rm --name nifi nifi-test:latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking a look at the dockerfile provided you can see the following volume definition

---

[image]

Then if you run

`docker image inspect apache/nifi:1.12.1`

[image]

As a result, when you execute the RUN command to create a folder under the conf directory it succeeds

**BUT** when you run the container the volumes are mounted and as a result they overwrite everything that is under the mountpoint `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf`

In your case the `flow` directory.

You can test this by editing your Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/nifi:1.12.1
# this will be overriden, by volumes
RUN mkdir -p /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/flow
# this will be available in the container environment
RUN mkdir -p /opt/nifi/nifi-current/flow
```

---

To tackle this you could

1. **clone the Dockerfile** of the image you use as base one (the one in
   FROM) and **remove the VOLUME directive** manually. Then build it and
   use in your FROM as base one.
2. You could try to avoid adding directories under the mount points specified in the Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me realize what's the case here. As a work-around I created the `flow` dir at the same level as `conf` dir. As it seems it does not interfere with the directed `VOLUME` path now. Do you have any clue why is this happening only in Linux though? If you try to recreate on Windows/macOS, the issue won't occur.